# jQuery unselect dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, attributes, selected

I have a dropdown menu for states. The first option is 'Please select state' and its value is 0 but a state is always selected it as the user picks a state from a previous page and it somehow gets state and selects it. I want it to be at value 0.

I have this code....

```
$('#shipstate option').attr('selected', '');
```

but this sets all my options to selected.

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to set the value of an element that happens to be a select to 0, now turn this phrase into jquery:

```
$('#shipstate').val(0)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will accept the answer in 10 minutes when it will allow me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#shipstate').val('');
```

OR

```
$('#shipstate').val(0);
```

And this will select the default ie. first `option`.

You can also do:

```
$('#shipstate').attr('selectedIndex', 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would set the value to the select element directly by using `.val()` jquery api.

**Method:**`.val()`

Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the value of every matched element.

Ref : http://api.jquery.com/val/

`$('#shipstate').val(0);`

Comment: Note that setting the dropdown to the first value does NOT deselect options that have been selected! But because the OP wants to set the first option, yes, this will set it.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the option using the following method.

```
 $('#shipstate option[value="0"]').prop('selected', true);
```

This is the best method to deselect the option.

```
 $('#shipstate option[value="0"]').prop('selected', false);
```